# QML share one instance of a component in different pages in a stackview

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, I have one instance of a Component (`id: sharedComponent`) which I would like to use in two QML `Page`s that are managed in a `StackView`. However, the `sharedComponent` is only visible when `page1` is active in `StackView`, i.e., the blue rectangle disappears as soon as `page2` is pushed on the `StackView`.

How can I share/use/see an instance of a component in multiple pages in QML?

MyPage.qml

```js
Page {
    default property alias mainContent: mainContent.data

    Item {
        id: mainContent
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

main.qml

```js
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: sharedComponent
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "blue"
        // in my actual software, this shared component would contain a Scene3D here
    }

    MyPage {
        id: page1
        mainContent: sharedComponent
    }
    MyPage {
        id: page2
        mainContent: sharedComponent
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: page1
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Button {
        text: "Switch Page"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            if(stackView.depth>1) {
                stackView.pop()
            } else {
                stackView.push(page2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to share an object, the shared object needs to be re-parented. When a different MyPage instance becomes visible, it needs to become the parent of the sharedObject. So start the pages with visible set to false.

MyPage.qml:

```
Page {
    property Item mainContent

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    onVisibleChanged: {
        if (visible) {
            // Take ownership of the shared object
            mainContent.parent = container
        }
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    ...

    Rectangle {
        id: sharedComponent
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "blue"
    }

    MyPage {
        id: page1
        mainContent: sharedComponent

        // When visible becomes true, page1 becomes the parent
        visible: false
    }
    MyPage {
        id: page2
        mainContent: sharedComponent

        // When visible becomes true, page2 becomes the parent
        visible: false
    }
}
```

Comment: OK your example works. However, you changed the property alias to a property Item. Will this instantiate use twice the memory for the sharedComponent? I think this will actually create a copy of shared component per page. The idea of using a shared instance was that this same instance is used and manipulated from within two pages AND that the memory of only one instance of the sharedComponent is allocated.

Comment: You can't use an alias because an alias cannot be reassigned at runtime. My code does not create a copy of the item either. You can see this for yourself by checking the value of mainContent. Add `console.log(mainContent)` in the onVisibleChanged handler and you will see the address stays the same as you switch between different owners.

Comment: How can I know in QML whether a property is copied or passed by reference?

Comment: I’m not an expert on that topic, but I believe QML follows [javascript rules](https://javascript.info/object-copy). Primitives copy their values, but objects just copy references.